# Increase Upload file size cakephp 3

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to upload files larger than 50 MB but only accepts less than 3 MB, how can i increase this limit?

already try adding the following in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]    
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value memory_limit 100M
```

the problem was here in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M   
post_max_size = 1000M
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was here in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M   
post_max_size = 1000M
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
    echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); // 100M
?>
```

If the output equals 100M php is configured properly and the size limit is enforced by the php script (laravel), if not the host doesn't allow increasing the file limit that high.

Either way I advise you to upload huge files in chunks with libraries like [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It is less prone to errors and timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an Apache httpd configuration (you don't specify); but you might be running into the server limitation before you're running into the PHP limitation:

[From the Apache Core documentation,](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) try adding the following line to your .htaccess file (or set it at the server level):

```
LimitRequestBody 50000000
```

("50000000" or the exact byte value you wish to use.)

Comment: Looks promising, never had this issue yet though and I had to configure servers for 300MB SQL Imports

Comment: i use wamp for the database, to configure that, where is the file?, in cakephp or wamp?

Comment: Add it to the .htaccess file that you posted.  I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard:  Normally, it's never an issue either, but I've run into the same thing on multiple server platforms (IIS, Tomcat, httpd, etc) where all looks well and you're smacking into a higher-level limit.  Typically  it happens with direct file uploads instead of the more general case; I think that the server guys all decided that having a DOS by uploading a 5GB zip file was easily covered by setting default limits.

Comment: I already did and still can not upload the file, also delete the "php_value" from .htaccess and follow me printing 100M